# How to insert rows into an Acumatica grid with a DataMember that is an unbound DAC?

Tags: acumatica

The goal is to insert multiple rows into a grid using a PXAction in Acumatica. The grid's DataMember is an unbound DAC. This is the current attempt. It only adds a single row. More rows are unable to be added after the first one.

```
public PXFilter<UnboundDAC> GridView;

public PXAction<MainDAC> InsertRow;

[PXButton(CommitChanges = true)]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Insert Row")]
protected void insertRow()
{
  UnboundDAC newline = new UnboundDAC();
  newline.IntField = Document.Current.FormIntField;
  
  GridView.Insert(newline);
}
```

UnboundDAC code:

```
using System;
using PX.Data;

namespace NS
{
  [Serializable]
  [PXCacheName("UnboundDAC")]
  public class UnboundDAC : IBqlTable
  {
    #region IntField
    [PXDBInt()]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Int Field")]
    public virtual int? IntField {get; set; }
    public abstract class intField : PX.Data.BQL.BqlInt.Field<intField> { }
    #endregion
  }
}
```

Comment: Can we see your DAC definition for UnboundDAC ?

Comment: @KyleVanderstoep this would be the code for UnboundDAC.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the PXDBInt attribute with this,

> ```
>    [PXInt(IsKey =true)]
> ```

Without a key, I think Acumatica treats the table like a setup screen (one row)